# Why angular add a string to my url?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small angular app that uses this configuration:

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl: 'home.html',   controller: 'mainCtrl'}).
    when('/report/fail', {templateUrl: 'fail.html',   controller: 'mainCtrl'}).
    when('/report/:url', {templateUrl: 'report.html',   controller: 'reportGeneralCtrl'}).
    when('/report/:id/:url', {templateUrl: 'report.html',   controller: 'reportUserCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

}]);

When I try to access some url directly, typing in the browser the url, angular add this string: "#.UqX3mNJN9Zo" to my url.

Why this happens?

Comment: Does the app work normally otherwise? Say, if you got the root of your app in `/a/` will a request to `/a/such-and-such` work correctly other than the string added to the URL?

Comment: Yes, the app works normally. If I'm on my root and click on any link to other views, the browser bar give the correct url, say "/report/myReportName". But if I try to access to www.myapp.com/report/myReportName angular adds the string #.UqX3mNJN9Zo to the url. Is that generated by ajax callbacks?

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, would you mind trying removing the html5mode? I'm trying to replicate it, but can't seem to get the hash in the URL.

Comment: With $locationProvider.html5Mode(false) trying to access directly, angular add #/ at the end.

Comment: But it doesn't add the weird string, right? Also, what browser are you using and what version of angular?

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.41 m Aura and angularJs 1.0.6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42801/discussion-between-tropicalista-and-rdodev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is caused by addThis script. probably this don't work well on angular.